# Chrome iFrame history not behaving correctly with 2 or more iFrames on page. (ver. 35.0.1916.114)

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

I have noticed that iframes are becoming mixed up with what iframe they actually belong to when the back button is pressed.

As an example I have made a jsfiddle. Press Run and then wait for the left iframe to refresh - then click any link inside the right iframe and then press chromes back button. You'll notice that the right iframe has lost its context and now has the same content as the left iframe.

http://jsfiddle.net/N4uEv/4/

I have been able to reproduce this in a few different ways (not just through using a setInterval timer).

This was not happening in the previous version of Chrome, and is not happening in firefox/ie/safari etc. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
<div id="iframe1">
    <iframe src="blabla" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0"     leftmargin="0" allowtransparency="true" width="100" height="400"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="iframe2">
    <iframe src="http://mobafire.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" allowtransparency="true" width="500" height="600"></iframe>
</div>


setInterval(function(){
       $('#iframe1').html(' ').html('<iframe src="blabla" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" allowtransparency="true" width="100" height="400"></iframe>');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I having similar problems with this version of Chrome...

Comment: @PavleGartner It's frustrating - seems like a problem quite a few people are running into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is affected by a known and still open bug that screws iframes contents when using back/forward buttons: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395791

Basically Chrome doesn't know which content to show in which frame after a history back/forward.

To solve this you need to add a unique `name` attribute to your iframes.
Eg:

```
<div id="iframe1">
    <iframe name="iframe1" src="blabla" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" allowtransparency="true" width="100" height="400"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="iframe2">
    <iframe name="iframe2" src="blabla" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" allowtransparency="true" width="100" height="400"></iframe>
</div>
```